# What is this construction material called, please?

Tags: walls, masonry, materials

[image]

It's used by some agency called 'Quantum Tech HD' on youtube, as a logo. I asked there for advice months ago but have received no response. Does someone here know? I'd be most interested in Canadian sources.

Comment: looks like the blocks are made from concrete

Comment: @jsotola  They are, but made to look like stone on the outside.

Comment: please add a link to the source of the image into your question

Comment: google `NovaBrik`

Comment: @jsotola: I wish I could oblige but I've just looked back over several hundred videos, trying to find that one, without success. Sorry about this. And thanks for your tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mortar-less brick.  It is attached to the building with screws into wood furring.

There are a few different companies making them, but the name you mention is not near the top of Google listings.  That company might only use them.

As long as you keep straight lines, they do seem easier to use than laying brick with mortar.  They cut easy with a wet saw.

A first timer DIY can probably install them.